# How can I change the parameters in Cytoscape to obtain this layout?

Tags: layout, cytoscape

I'm currently trying to apply an Edge-weighted Spring Embedded Layout algorithm in Cytoscape to a network, following the Materials and Methods from a study. When I apply the Layout, I'm not obtaining the same results.

In my case I'm having some nodes pointing outwards and some others highly concentrated in the middle of the graph, but I want the nodes to be equally distributed in the surface. This is what I have:

[image: What I obtain]

And this is what I want:

[image: What I want to have]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the weights on your edges.  You'll get very different values depending on the weights and how those weights are being interpreted.  You'll undoubtedly need to open up the Layout->Settings... dialog for the spring embedded layout and play with the values to get the results you want.